# LibGDX - setProjectionMatrix() "hiding" a Sprite

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to draw a `Sprite` but it just appears for a frame when I first run my program, and then immediately disappears. I am working with a `Stage`, a Tiled map and two `Batches`, which I hope is not a problem.

It pretty much looked like the sprite was hiding behind something else, but I made completely sure that nothing was being drawn after it. So after a long time messing around, I found out that deleting the `setProjectionMatrix()` method "solved" my problem, since the sprite showed perfectly somehow.

I don't understand the reason why this happened at all, and I don't want to just delete the method and have sprites following the camera around, so:

Why or how would a setProjectionMatrix() method "hide" a Sprite? Is it altering the order in which my sprites are drawing? And most importantly, how do I fix it?

Here's my `render` method:

```java
public void render(float delta) {
    Render.cleanScreen(); //Render is a class i made with useful static stuff, like the Batch i am using.
                          //This method is pretty much just a Gdx.gl.glClearColor() method.
    
    tmr.setView(camera); // tileMapRenderer
    tmr.render();
    b2dr.render(world, camera.combined); // Box2DDebugRenderer
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
    
    Render.batch.begin(); 
    sprite2.draw(Render.batch); //The sprite i want to draw
    Render.batch.end();

    hudBatch.begin();
    sprite1.draw(hudBatch); //This works fine
    hudBatch.end();

    Render.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
```

Edit: Someone asked for extra info, so:

• [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWenQ.png) is what my game looks like with the setProjectionMatrix (after the first frame when the Sprite dissapears) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV6oI.png) is what it looks when i delete it. You can clearly see the red square(the Sprite).

• I am currently using a FitViewport.

Comment: Is `camera` the same camera instance the stage is using?

Comment: Yes, it is the same camera.

Comment: A projection matrix won't change the draw order, but it's theoretically possible it could draw your sprite behind the others if it has been moved in the Z direction and depth testing is on (which it shouldn't be if you didn't turn it on). But if it's the same camera that you're using everywhere and you haven't modified its parameters, then that's not possible either.

Comment: Comparison screenshots with and without using the projection matrix could help. And knowing which viewport you're using.

Comment: You said it looked like the Sprite is hiding behind something else, but to me it looks like it’s not showing whatsoever? Is that right? Do your FitViewport dimensions happen to exactly match the window dimensions? Otherwise I can’t think of how the Sprite would be drawn right where you expect when not using a camera.

Comment: Oh wait, it’s the same SpriteBatch that the Stage uses? If so, then the projection matrix that the stage gets from the camera will still be set when you continue using the SpriteBatch after drawing the stage. So that would mean the issue is likely to do with the cameras not actually being the same camera instance. Otherwise, when you set the projection matrix, nothing would be changing. You may want to check with the debugger.

Comment: I fixed it. I am sorry to have bothered you, the solution was really dumb. Thank you so much for your help though, it actually helped me understand some stuff better.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. No worries. I’ve had problems like that where several people were trying to help me figure it out, I spend hours on it, and it turns out to be something trivial like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... I just realized my coworker accidentally deleted the viewport.update() method.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Stage.draw()` calls `apply()` on the Stage's Viewport, but never restores the OpenGL Viewport to what it was before. I'm guessing that your stage uses FitViewport, so it is cropping part of the screen. If you want different viewport behavior for stuff you draw outside your stage, you should create a separate viewport for that, and call `viewport.apply()` before you start rendering the other stuff.

Side note: if you are lazy loading anything that uses native memory (like SpriteBatch and Texture, things implementing Disposable) and storing a reference in a static variable (your Render class), make sure you dispose all of it and null it out in your game's `destroy()` method. Otherwise, on Android you will be leaking that stuff and it will fail to work when you reopen your game.

Another side note: In my opinion, the Sprite class should not be used unless you have hundreds of them and they aren't moving much (in which case it might have slightly better performance). Sprite is a weird conflation of an asset (a TextureRegion) and game state data. As a result, it can create design issues that you have to work around, such as when you want to animate it or flip it. It is better to create your own GameObject class that references a TextureRegion (a single instance of which can be shared by many elements), and has its own variables for position, color, rotation, etc. Then draw it with the appropriate SpriteBatch.draw method using those properties. In my game, I have a wrapper interface around `TextureRegion` that can alternately wrap `Animation<TextureRegion>` so my GameObject class can use either and it can be swapped easily. This makes the code more flexible to change.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do understand what you're saying, but I am still a little bit confused. I don't want two different viewports, I want my Sprite2 to fit in with the stuff i already had. So here's what I don't get about your reply: If I declared and created the FitViewport in my main screen and passed it over to my Stage when i first created it, why wouldn't the OpenGL viewport be updated? Isn't the Viewport i created supposed to "coordinate" both?

Comment: I was taking a guess at what could be the issue but if you want to use the same viewport for everything, then ignore what I said. It’s something else.